# What does "piss yellow" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Ocean's Eight (2018)*, Amita inspecting  a colorless diamond
and her mother interrupts her:

> Amita: This Diamond us a K...at best
>
> Amita's Mother: It's an H.
>
> Amita: You're out of your mind? This is **piss yellow**.

What does "piss yellow" mean here?

Comment: Piss is used as an adjective.  You can find the rest in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can add a noun naming something of a well known colour to a colour name to form an adjective used to denote a colour shade. Some examples: snow white, sky blue, blood red, coal black, sea green, leaf green, rose pink, chestnut brown, canary (or primrose) yellow.

'Piss', is a slang word for urine. Its use implies contempt. Not everybody's urine is always coloured yellow, sometimes it is almost clear. Certain foods, beetroot, for example, can change the colour.

The most valuable diamonds are clear in appearance, and any yellow tint will reduce the value. They are often classified with letters according to colour. The scale begins with the letter D, representing colourless, and continues with increasing presence of colour to the letter Z, or light yellow or brown. Amita says the diamond is a K (faint yellow), but her mother says it is H (near colourless). Amita then disagrees, saying, in colourful language, that it is quite yellow.

[image]

Z on the left, D on the right

[image]

[Diamond colour scale viewer](https://www.gia.edu/gia-about/4cs-color#:%7E:text=GIA%27s%20color%2Dgrading%20scale%20for,defined%20range%20of%20color%20appearance.)

Comment: You overlooked my favorite: baby-shit brown.

Comment: @JeffreyCarney - I did think of 'shit brown' but delicacy, already strained by the piss bottle, held me back.

Answer (score 1):

"Piss" is slang for "urine." And the color of urine is yellow. So it's a shade of yellow.

I don't think it's an official shade of yellow, so I suppose everyone might have their own opinion of exactly which shad3e of yellow it resembles.

Comment: 'Vomit beige' isn't official, either, but I have heard it used by people to describe decor after viewing apartments in the UK.